# how to query ArrayList<Funds> and store in an array

Tags: java, android

I have an ArrayList which stores 100 instances of a POJO named Funds. Here is what Funds looks like:

```
public class Funds
{
  private String InvestmentName;

  private String PrimaryInvestmentObjective;

  private String AgencyOrMissionRelatedNeeds;
}
```

here is what my ArrayList looks like: `ArrayList<Funds>`

I need to get a complete list of InvestmentName from fundList, and I need to store all 100 `InvestmentNames` in an array. I tried to look to see if `ArrayList` had some kind of filter but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

please you can use java 8 stream api like

```
List<String> names= funds.stream().map(Funds:InvestmentName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

please note this code is not test but it should work fine

Comment: you can still call stream() on array and in android once you are using java8

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to write a get method for your InvestmentName member and you also need to write a method that iterates through the ArrayList and puts each InvestmentName into an array.

Answer (score 0):

So you have an `ArrayList<Funds>` and you want to transform that into an `ArrayList<String>` or `String[]` of investment names, is that right?

Have you tried something like this?

```
ArrayList<String> investmentNames = new ArrayList<>();
for (Funds f : fundsList) {
  investmentNames.add(f.getInvestmentName());
}
```

If you really want to convert the result into an array (`String[]`) afterwards you would call this:

```
String[] investmentNamesArray = investmentNames.toArray(new String[investmentNames.size()]);
```

However you should avoid mixing arrays and `List`s (*Effective Java Item 25: Prefer lists to arrays*) and just use `investmentNames` directly.